# ComboBox returning System.Data.DataRow View For Every Value

Tags: c#, .net

I am building a point of sales software in C#. For adding a new product, I have created a combo box that would show all the categories from the mysql server. However, when I run the program only 3 values show up in my combo box and all of them have the same data: System.Data.DataRowView. Here's my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void LoadDataIntoComboBoxes()
        {
            CategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "Column_KeyValue";
            CategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "Column_DisplayValue";
            CategoryComboBox.DataSource = GetComboBoxData(2).DefaultView;
            SupplierComboBox.DataSource = GetComboBoxData(3);
        }

        private DataTable GetComboBoxData(int listTypeID)
        {
            DataTable dtrecord = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ApplicationSetting.ConnectionString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_ListTypesData_LoadDataIntoComboBox", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListTypeID", listTypeID);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtrecord.Load(sdr);
                }
            }

            return dtrecord;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` from your databatable columns before fill the datasource with data :

```
CategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "Column_KeyValue";
CategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "Column_DisplayValue";
CategoryComboBox.DataSource = GetComboBoxData(2);
```

Comment: please update your code in question to see what you change, it must work ! try with GetComboBoxData(2).DefaultView;

Comment: I have tried with .DefaultView, still not working though. I have updated the code

Comment: I have also included an image for your help

Comment: change "Column_KeyValue" and "Column_DisplayValue" with your column name in datatable!!